# what is proper way to use spring washer and washer

Tags: tools

I have one socket screw,one socket bolt,two nuts and spring washers,washers.and I need to know what is proper way to use.what order should i put them.
does spring washer generally go on the nut side or bolt side.i tried four different ways and i attached image of it.

[image: examples]

Comment: Interesting question, but it may depend on exactly what you're holding together with the bolt.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of the flat washer is spread out the clamping force over a sufficient area of the material being clamped and to prevent the lock washer from tearing into the material as the nut is being turned. Given the small sizes of the bolt heads in your pictures I would say that you should have two flat washers on each bolt in addition to the spring washer.

The order should be bolt head, flat washer, materials being clamped, flat washer, spring washer, nut. If you only have one flat washer per bolt, and if the material next to the bolt head is sufficiently hard to resist deformation, then the one flat washer should be on the nut side.